# Python regular expression (matching in list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

Looking to extract only 7 digit numbers from this list that starts with the distance matrix, nothing after the underscore

The list:

`['data_train_3366094.dump','agile_234444.pkl','distanceMatrix_1517144.dump', 'distanceMatrix_3366094_1.dump']`

expecting output: `1517144 , 3366094`

Comment: `(?<=distanceMatrix_)\d{7}\b`? Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jgySfR/1

Comment: #half solution

import re

string = ['data_train_3366094.dump','agile_234444.pkl','distanceMatrix_1517144.dump', 'distanceMatrix_3366094_1.dump']

#search using regex
for i in string:
    result = [i for i in string if i.startswith('distanceMatrix_')]
    #x = re.findall('[0-9]+', result)
print(result)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to explode(), separating with _ and .
Then match for numeric value

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot do that as we are expecting to extract the numbers starting after distanceMatrix_ for analysis